# Type error with <{[key: string]: Thread}>

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to add my *Thread* object to my variable *threads*.

Here is what I realized:

```
export class ThreadService {
   newThreads: Thread[];
   threads: Observable<{ [key: string]: Thread }>;
}

addThread(keyThread: string, newThread: Thread): void {
   this.threadService.newThreads.push(newThread);
   this.threadService.threads = Observable.of({[keyThread]: newThread});
}
```

Do you know why it doesn't work ?

Comment: what do you need, an array of `Thread` (`Thread[]`) or a dictionnary with string as keys and `Thread` as values (`{ [key: string]: Thread }`) ?

Comment: @n00dl3
I need a dictionnary with string as keys and Thread as values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually not related to RxJS, you have mixed types. You defined `threads` in `ThreadService` as:

```
Observable<{ [key: string]: Thread }>
```

This means you have an Observable that emits objects of for example this:

```
{
    a: thread1 as Thread,
    b: thread2 as Thread,
}
```

However you're trying to assign it something different with `Observable.of(this.threadService.newThreads)`.

The `newThreads` property is of type `Thread[]` which not assignable to `{ [key: string]: Thread }`.

Comment: Yes, but I can not find the right syntax for this equality.
I have a parameter of the function `addThread`, a variable key and a variable newThread.
`this.threadService.threads = Observable.of([key]: newThread);`

Comment: @Floriane Then what do you expect `threads` Observable to emit?